# Is it possible to serialize field of an object with Spring Data?

Tags: java, serialization, spring-data

For example:

I have an entity, which contains a field of a serializable type. I want save the entity so, that field will be stored as serialized data. When entity will be loaded again, value of the field must be restored from its serialized state.

So, once again, is it possible with Spring Data?

I tell about generic Spring Data instead of any more specific implementation such as Spring Data JPA, because I use Spring Data Neo4j. And it will be useful, if suggested approach will work with any specific implementation.

Comment: Workaround, but you could have a byte array that is populated when you set the object.  Then you could have the object be @Transient.  You can then deserialize when you get call the getter for the Object.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to do something similar: convert hibernate's Date/Timestamp objects to Java 8's LocalDateTime objects in my entity POJOs.

I achieved that by creating an attribute-converter that `implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp>`. I also added the `@Converter(autoApply = true)` annotation so that the serialization/deserialization happened automatically for all entities.

You can find details in [this](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/) excellent blogpost.